# How to read avro file as json text in Google cloud storage

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, avro

I want to be able to read an avro file as json using something similar to  'hdfs -text *.avro' but in Google cloud storage. I will be parsing the json in a python script

I am looking for a gsutil command way to read avro files as json, similar to how we do in hdfs

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct way to read Avro files

**How to read an Avro file as JSON text in Google Cloud Storage:**

1. Install the `avro-tools` command on your local machine.
2. Run the following gsutil command:

```
gsutil cat gs://<bucket>/<path/to/avro/file.avro> | avro-tools tojson > <path/to/json/file.json>
```

This will read the Avro file from Google Cloud Storage, convert it to JSON, and write the JSON output to the specified file.

3. Parse the JSON file in your Python script using a JSON parser such as the `json` module.

Here is an example of a Python script that parses the JSON file `my-json-file.json`:

```py
import json

with open("my-json-file.json", "r") as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

# Iterate over the JSON data and do something with it
for record in json_data:
    print(record)
```